# How can i set admin button for admins in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, admin

I want to show floatactionbutton for only admins in my app, but how can i do this i do not know.
Could you help me?
By the way, when i login my app, my informations update what they are.
I tried boolean isAdmin (and also lots of ways int etc.) and after this i set manually, but after that it update false or it deleted auto. again...

I just want to if i admin, then only i can use this button that's it.

my codes :

```
return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: provider.isAdmin == 1 ? CreateNewShop() : Container(),

        body: HomePageBody());
```

and also google sign in codes:

```
 Future login() async {
    isSigningIn = true;

    final user = await googleSignIn.signIn();
    if (user == null) {
      isSigningIn = false;
      return;
    } else {
      final googleAuth = await user.authentication;

      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
      final existingUserDocs = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Users')
          .where('uid', isEqualTo: user.id)
          .get();
      final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
      if (existingUserDocs.docs.isEmpty) {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(uid).set({
          'email': user.email,
          'username': user.displayName,
          'uid': uid,
          'userPhotoUrl': user.photoUrl,
          
        });
      } else {
        return null;
      }

      isSigningIn = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: How are you setting isAdmin, and where are you declaring it?

Comment: i created googleSignIn in changenotifierprovider, and i used login part. I mean if my uid has exist in the system, then just i can log in but im not log in in the system, then i sign up automatically with my google infos. I add isAdmin here, but i can not get any success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Visibility` Widget to make hide and visible of a Widget

For more information visit [Flutter Visibility class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Visibility-class.html)

```
floatingActionButton: Visibility(
          visible: provider.isAdmin == 1,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: (){},
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: yes but i said that i can not do provider.isAdmin == 1 , because when i login the app, my all informations are rewrite, or set. I wrote above the codes.

Comment: you should save isAdmin information into SharedPreference then you will be able to access isAdmin information when ever you want.

Comment: any other way ?? +++

Comment: sharedPreference is the best way I think

Comment: and also i use "?" this thing for visibility. I just need to different system but how i do not know